# How can I remove currency in an Angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm using the directive for displaying money in proper format from this url http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/xKrYp/

Does anyone know how can I remove the $ symbol from the output value and have only the actual amount converted?

Tried few different things but I was not able to accomplish what I was looking for.

Here is the directive as well:

```
app.directive('realTimeCurrency', function ($filter, $locale) {
    var decimalSep = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.DECIMAL_SEP;
    var toNumberRegex = new RegExp('[^0-9\\' + decimalSep + ']', 'g');
    var trailingZerosRegex = new RegExp('\\' + decimalSep + '0+$');
    var filterFunc = function (value) {
        return $filter('currency')(value);
    };

    function getCaretPosition(input){
        if (!input) return 0;
        if (input.selectionStart !== undefined) {
            return input.selectionStart;
        } else if (document.selection) {
            // Curse you IE
            input.focus();
            var selection = document.selection.createRange();
            selection.moveStart('character', input.value ? -input.value.length : 0);
            return selection.text.length;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    function setCaretPosition(input, pos){
        if (!input) return 0;
        if (input.offsetWidth === 0 || input.offsetHeight === 0) {
            return; // Input's hidden
        }
        if (input.setSelectionRange) {
            input.focus();
            input.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
        }
        else if (input.createTextRange) {
            // Curse you IE
            var range = input.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', pos);
            range.moveStart('character', pos);
            range.select();
        }
    }

    function toNumber(currencyStr) {
        return parseFloat(currencyStr.replace(toNumberRegex, ''), 10);
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, modelCtrl) {    
            modelCtrl.$formatters.push(filterFunc);
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (newViewValue) {
                var oldModelValue = modelCtrl.$modelValue;
                var newModelValue = toNumber(newViewValue);
                modelCtrl.$viewValue = filterFunc(newModelValue);
                var pos = getCaretPosition(elem[0]);
                elem.val(modelCtrl.$viewValue);
                var newPos = pos + modelCtrl.$viewValue.length -
                                   newViewValue.length;
                if ((oldModelValue === undefined) || isNaN(oldModelValue)) {
                    newPos -= 3;
                }
                setCaretPosition(elem[0], newPos);
                return newModelValue;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: For clarity, do you want the textcontrol not to show the $ sign?

Comment: @defaultcheckbox correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try https://github.com/bcherny/format-as-currency :)

Or if you want to use your own version, pass an empty string as a 2nd argument to the `currency` filter. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency

Comment: Thanks, trying yours now

Comment: Can I remove the currency completely from your directive?

Comment: Yes, look at this example but use an empty string instead of Yuan. https://github.com/bcherny/format-as-currency#with-a-custom-currency-symbol

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="LoanDetailsVM.LoanAmount" format-as-currency currency-filter="" placeholder="Loan amount"> that is what I put but I still get the dollar sign.

Comment: Defined a currency filter, otherwise it will use the built in one. In your custom currency filter, set the currency symbol to `''`.

Comment: Same output, if you want I can share teamviewer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126257/discussion-between-laziale-and-bcherny).